# Speed up this Sybase stored procedure

Tags: sql, query-optimization, sybase

I have this stored procedure which I am using to populate a user table. It seems slow because it is taking around avg. 6s to return the records. Is there anything else I can do to tweak this sproc to make it faster?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usmGetPendingAuthorizations
(
    @empCorpId char(8) = null,
    @empFirstName char(30) = null,
    @empLastName char(30) = null,
    @accessCompletionStatus char(20) = null,
    @ownerCorpId char(8) = null,
    @reqCorpId char(8) = null,
    @reqDate datetime = null,
    @rowCount int = 100
)
AS BEGIN       

    SET ROWCOUNT @rowCount

    SELECT
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.RequestorCorpId))) AS ReqCorpId, 
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.AccessCompletionStatus))) AS AccessCompletionStatus, 
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.Comment))) AS ReqComment, 
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.ValidLoginInd))) AS ValidLoginInd, 
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.OwnerCorpId))) AS OwnerCorpId, 
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.UserTypeCode))) AS UserTypeCode, 
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.SelectMethod))) AS SelectMethod, 
        pa.ExpirationDate AS ExpirationDate, 
        pa.RequestorDate AS ReqDate, 
        pa.BeginDate AS BeginDate, 
        pa.EndDate AS EndDate, 
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.UserGroupTypeCode))) AS UserGroupTypeCode,
        pa.SubsidiaryId AS SubsidiaryId,    
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.EmployeeCorpId))) AS EmpCorpId,
        emp.empKeyId AS EmpKeyId,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(emp.firstName)) AS EmpFirstName,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(emp.lastName)) AS EmpLastName
    FROM
        dbo.PendingAuthorization AS pa JOIN capmark..EmployeeDataExtract AS emp
    ON
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.EmployeeCorpId))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(emp.corporateId)))
    WHERE
        UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.EmployeeCorpId))) LIKE ISNULL(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@empCorpId))), '%')
        AND UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(emp.firstName))) LIKE ISNULL('%' + UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@empFirstName))) + '%', '%')
        AND UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(emp.lastName))) LIKE ISNULL('%' + UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@empLastName))) + '%', '%')
        AND pa.AccessCompletionStatus LIKE ISNULL(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@accessCompletionStatus))), '%')
        AND pa.OwnerCorpId LIKE ISNULL(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ownerCorpId))), '%')
        AND pa.RequestorCorpId LIKE ISNULL(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@reqCorpId))), '%')
        AND DATEDIFF(dd, pa.RequestorDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ISNULL(@reqDate, pa.RequestorDate), 101)) = 0

    SET ROWCOUNT 0
END
```

Comment: Get rid of all of those `LIKE` statements.

Comment: How many records are returning? 6s for zero records is much different than 6s for 1 million records?

Comment: You say 'anything else' - could you perhaps say what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the liberal use of functions, especially in the join.  Where functions are used in this way Sybase cannot take advantage of indexes on those fields.  Take for example the join

```
ON
    UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.EmployeeCorpId))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(emp.corporateId)))
```

Are all those trims and uppers really needed?

If you have dirty data stored - mixed case, with some leading and some trailing space, I suggest that you try to tighten up the way the data are stored and/or updated - don't allow such data to get in.  Carry out a one-time scrub of the data to make all corporate Ids uppercase with no trailing or leading spaces.

Once you've got clean data you can add an index on corporateId column in the EmployeeDataExtract table (or rebuild it if one already exists) and change the join to

```
ON
    pa.EmployeeCorpId = emp.corporateId
```

If you really can't ensure clean data in the PendingAuthorization table then you'd have to leave the functions wrapping on that side of the join, but at least the index on the `emp` table will be available for the optimiser to consider.

The use of LIKE with leading edge wildcards makes indexes unusable, but that may be unavoidable in your case.

It looks like the PendingAuthorization.RequestorDate field is used to select data only for one date - the one supplied in @reqDate.  You could transform that part of the WHERE clause to a range query, then an index on the date field could be used.
To do that you would use just the date part of @reqDate (ignoring time of day) and then derive from that 'date+1'.  These would be the values used.  Whether this would help much depends on how many RequestorDate days are present in the PendingAuthorization table.

Comment: It turns out that it was the functions being used on the JOIN that was slowing down the sproc.

Answer (score 0):

Although you seem never accepted any answer, I will try to help you :).

First, I would revise the WHERE clause. Instead of your LIKEs:

```
UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.EmployeeCorpId))) LIKE ISNULL(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@empCorpId))), '%')
```

I would use this:

```
(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.EmployeeCorpId))) LIKE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@empCorpId)))) OR (@empCorpId IS NULL)
```

So, can you try the following WHERE clause instead of yours to see if there is any difference in performance?

```
WHERE
    (UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.EmployeeCorpId))) LIKE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@empCorpId))) OR @empCorpId IS NULL)
    AND (UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(emp.firstName))) LIKE '%' + UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@empFirstName))) + '%' OR @empFirstName IS NULL)
    AND (UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(emp.lastName))) LIKE '%' + UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@empLastName))) + '%' OR @empLastName IS NULL)
    AND (pa.AccessCompletionStatus LIKE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@accessCompletionStatus))) OR @accessCompletionStatus IS NULL)
    AND (pa.OwnerCorpId LIKE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ownerCorpId))) OR @ownerCorpId IS NULL)
    AND (pa.RequestorCorpId LIKE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@reqCorpId))) OR @reqCorpId IS NULL)
    AND (DATEDIFF(dd, pa.RequestorDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ISNULL(@reqDate, pa.RequestorDate), 101)) = 0)
```

Second, in general, SELECT works faster if columns referenced in WHERE clause are indexed appropriately.

Then, DATEDIFF along with CONVERT in WHERE clause are not going to speed up your query either.

But, the main question is: how many rows are in the joined tables? Because 6 seconds could be not that bad. You can check/play with Query plan to find out any potential bottle-necks.

Comment: There's roughly around 500K+ rows in the capmark..EmployeeDataExtract table.

Comment: I would look at the query plan then.

Comment: The reason for all the LIKEs is that an end user can use any combination of these input parameters to query.  The only reason for the join is that the firstName and lastName is stored in the Employee table where the Pending Auth table just stores the employee's id.

Comment: Please see my edit for the WHERE clause. I would definitely recommend looking at query plan